# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.setReadOnly(Z)V

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, nosuchmethoderror

I have a spring boot application that provides a microservice and uses hibernate libraries for database access.

My main class is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories

public class CircularsMicroservice {

    @Autowired
    private CircularsService circularsService;



    //microservice called here
    @RequestMapping(value="/circulars-list", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    List<GmCirculars> getAllCircularsForOrganization(@RequestBody  CircularsParams circularsParams)
    {

        System.out.println("Circular Microservice called.....Params are:"+circularsParams.getOrganizationId()+", "+circularsParams.isActiveOnly()+", "+circularsParams.getStartOffset());
        List<GmCirculars> circularsList =
                circularsService.fetchAllCircularsForOrganization(circularsParams.getOrganizationId(), circularsParams.isActiveOnly(), circularsParams.getStartOffset());//invoke the method to get the circulars list


        return circularsList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 


        SpringApplication springApp= new SpringApplication(CircularsMicroservice.class);

        //configuration of db is in properties file


        springApp.run(args);
        System.out.println("done");


    }



}
```

Additional classes that can be related to errors:

```
/**
 * The Class CircularsService.
 */
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class CircularsService {

    @Autowired
    private IGmCircularsDAO gmCircularDao;



    @Value("${circulars.maxRows}")
    private int circularsMaxRows;


   //..................some other methods.............//


    public List<GmCirculars> fetchAllCircularsForOrganization(BigDecimal orgId, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset) {

        GmCirculars criteria = new GmCirculars();
        criteria.setOrganizationId(orgId);
        return gmCircularDao.find(criteria, activeOnly, startOffset, circularsMaxRows);
    }

}
```

Interface IGmCircularsDAO.

```
@Repository
public interface IGmCircularsDAO  {


    GmCirculars saveOrUpdate(GmCirculars obj);
    boolean markAsDeleted(BigDecimal rowId);
    List<GmCirculars> find(GmCirculars obj, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset, int maxRows);



}
```

The class GmCircularsDaoImpl:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class GmCircularsDaoImpl extends ParentDAO implements IGmCircularsDAO {


    @Override
    public List<GmCirculars> find(GmCirculars obj, boolean activeOnly, int startOffset, int maxRows) {
        Session session = null;
        List<GmCirculars> discounts = null;

        try {
            if (null != obj) {

                //session = sessionFactory.openSession(); //commented by Zaid
                session= this.getSession(); //Added by Zaid

                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(GmCirculars.class);

                if (null != obj.getId() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getId())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", obj.getId()));
                }

                if (StringUtil.isNotNullOrEmpty(obj.getTitle())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("title", obj.getTitle(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
                }

                if(null != obj.getOrganizationId()) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("organizationId", obj.getOrganizationId()));
                }


                if (null != obj.getTypeId() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getTypeId())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("typeId", obj.getTypeId()));
                }


                if (null != obj.getSerialNo() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getSerialNo())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("serialNo", obj.getSerialNo()));
                }

                if (null != obj.getYear() && !BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(obj.getYear())) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("year", obj.getYear()));
                }


                if (activeOnly) {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active", BigDecimal.ONE));
                }
                else {
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.ne("active", CommonConstants.DELETED_STATUS), Restrictions.isNull("active"))); //Except for deleted ones -> NVL(active,2)
                }


                //LIMIT startOffset, maxRows;
                criteria.setFirstResult(startOffset);
                criteria.setMaxResults(maxRows);

                criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
                criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
                discounts = criteria.list();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return discounts;
    }

     //Other methods..................


}
```

The class ParentDAO:

```
@Transactional
public class ParentDAO {


        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        protected Session getSession() {

            if(entityManager!=null)
                System.out.println("entity manager instantiated...");

            return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        }


}
```

My jar files that are related to database is below:

[image: My jar files that are related to database]

When I call the microservice **getAllCircularsForOrganization(@RequestBody  CircularsParams circularsParams)** I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.setReadOnly(Z)V
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:405) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:376) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:572) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:360) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.dao.impl.GmCircularsDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$daf36992.find(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at ae.gov.adm.saeed.service.CircularsService.fetchAllCircularsForOrganization(CircularsService.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at ae.gov.adm.CircularsMicroservice.getAllCircularsForOrganization(CircularsMicroservice.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

How to fix? Thanks.

Note that the error occurs here:

```
return gmCircularDao.find(criteria, activeOnly, startOffset, circularsMaxRows);
```

Comment: How does your pom.xml look like? There are many jars of the same kind with differenct versions

Comment: I don't use pom for security restrictions at my place.

Comment: Then you should check if you use all the correct version of the JAR files that Spring Boot defines . How did you get the JARs?

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. Use maven or gradle to manage your dependencies. Frankly speaking NOT using those is a bigger security risk then using them.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I downloaded them one by one, and it seems that's the reason. I will try to use Maven at home and find out the exact jars needed. Thanks.

Comment: @M.Deinum, trust me I tried but I am not the decision maker.

Comment: Not using a build framework (at least to manage the dependencies) is dangerous. You will mix versions of frameworks or modules from different versions of frameworks and include jars that contain security vulnerabilities. All of those will be solved by using Maven (or Gradle) and use the Spring Boot starters. You have curated dependencies as well as an easy upgrade path.